# Bot is not properly sending custom emojis discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, emoji

I'm having trouble using custom emoji in discord.js. When I try to make the bot use the emoji, It Always returns strange. Command Is:
`message.channel.send(':emoji name:emoji id')` and When I try to use it, the bot responds with: `:emoji name:`. But if I copy paste the `:emoji name:` It actually sends the emoji.

I tried with only the `emoji id` or only with `:emoji name:` and it still sends `:emoji name:`. What can I do?

Comment: Is it an animated emoji? If it is you have to do `<a:emoji name:emoji id>`

Comment: @SP73 It is not an animated emoji :( I really don't know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing this inside of discord...

`\`

and copy and paste it into your code?

You would need to format the emoji like this:

`<:emoji-name:emoji_id>`

example:

`<:CL_Discord:929513964805685248>`

Comment: I tried like so, `<:emoji-name:emoji_id>`, and it still only sends the text: `:emoji-name:`, removing the `emoji_id`